# Cedet cannot properly parse the time.h under /usr/include

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

I configured my cedet almost the same with http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html.

Thanks alexott , most of the time it works well, but I found that it can not well parse the tm struct in /usr/include/time.h.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void){
    struct tm times;
    FILE file;
}
```

When using `M-x semantic-ia-fast-jump`, the struct FILE is correct, but semantic finds the struct tm in `wchar.h`, not in `time.h`.
The problem seems to be there is a forward declaration in `wchar.h` for the `struct tm`.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to the Emacs or CEDET teams, rather than a question.

Comment: not sure whether other one has the same problem,or just some configurations neded

Answer (score 1):

In my copy of time.h, it appears that the symbol `__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD` is showing up in front of the struct declaration, and is befuddling the parser.  You can fix that quickly by just adding that and `__END_NAMESPACE_STD` to the variable `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map` as mapping to empty.  Then delete your semanticdb cache files (in ~/.semanticdb) related to time.h, or just everything in /usr/include, and restart emacs.  time.h should get reparsed, and things should work ok for time.h after that... unless you want to use std::tm or something.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. But even I added the two symbol and reconstruct the smeanticdb, it couldn't find the right place. I also found that the symbol __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD seems to have no impact for the parser since it appears almost before every declaration.